# convert this string to an object with JavaScript with a non-conforming format

Tags: javascript

I'd like to convert this string:

```
"Allergies: adas \n other: asdasdfgfdfbfb \n hola:hola"
```

to an object like

```
{
"Allergies":"adas",
"other":"asdasdfgfdfbfb",
"hola":"hola"
}
```

How can I achieve this, including the removal of the whitespace?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Use `split()` multiple times. First to split it into lines at `\n`, then to split each line into `key:value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this by splitting into arrays:

```js
const string = "Allergies: adas \n other: asdasdfgfdfbfb \n hola:hola";
console.log(Object.fromEntries(string.split('\n').map(inner => inner.split(':')).map(([s1, s2]) => [s1.trim(), s2.trim()])));
```